# Can the width of an input to a module be determined inside the module?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017 page 328, the following example is shown :

```
module ram_model (address, write, chip_select, data);

  parameter data_width = 8;
  parameter ram_depth = 256;
  localparam addr_width = clogb2(ram_depth);
  input [addr_width - 1:0] address;
  input write, chip_select;
  inout [data_width - 1:0] data;

  //define the clogb2 function
  function integer clogb2 (input [31:0] value);
  value = value - 1;
  for (clogb2 = 0; value > 0; clogb2 = clogb2 + 1)
    value = value >> 1;
  endfunction

  logic [data_width - 1:0] data_store[0:ram_depth - 1];

  //the rest of the ram model

endmodule: ram_model
```

How does it make sense that the "address" input width determined by "addr_width" which is an output of a function inside the module?

Comment: Basically, the function is executed at compile time rather than run time. You can do this sort of thing in VHDL, too.

Answer (score 4):

That code is from section 13.4.3 *Constant functions*.

The key here is that `clogb2` meets all the criteria of being a **constant** function.
As the Std states, constant function calls are evaluated at **elaboration** time.  Since this happens before runtime, the returned value is treated as a constant.

Not all functions can be used this way.

Refer also to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.10.4 *Elaboration considerations*, for further discussion on elaboration time.